# Can't use a Doctrine repository as user provider

Tags: security, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to create a [custom user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html).

I defined my `UserProvider` as a service:

```
myvendor.user_provider:
  class: MyVendor\UserBundle\Service\Security\UserProvider
```

This class is a `DocumentRepository`:

```
namespace MyVendor\UserBundle\Service\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentNotFoundException;

class UserProvider extends DocumentRepository implements UserProviderInterface {
    //public function loadUserBy...
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager, none given, called in /home/www/dev/public/myapp/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 258 and defined in /home/www/dev/public/myapp/vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/DocumentRepository.php line 68
```

Seems like the document manager has not been created yet at that point, because I also tried injecting it, but it complains about its own dependencies, like the `UnitOfWork`.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service definition was tricky

```
myvendor.user_provider:
    class: MyVendor\UserBundle\Service\Security\UserProvider
    factory_service: doctrine.odm.mongodb
    factory_method:  getRepository
    arguments: [ 'MyVendorUserBundle:User\User' ]
```